# Search mongodb documents with C# driver using a builder where all elements in an array match a filter

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to search MongoDB documents with the C# driver (I'm using version 2.19.1) using a builder where all elements in an array of a document match a filter.

I have documents of type MyDocument.
Each MyDocument has a list of MyElements

I want to filter all MyDocuments where **ALL** MyElements adhere to an arbitrary filter.

Furthermore, I have the following example code:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

public class MyDocument
{
    public List<MyElement> MyElements { get; set; }

    // other properties here
}

public class MyElement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    // other properties here
}

// Set up your MongoDB client and database
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("myDatabase");
var collection = database.GetCollection<MyDocument>("myCollection");

// Define the maximum number of "Count" to match against
int maxCount = 3;

// This is the filter I need to apply to ALL "MyElements" in a MyDocument
var myElementsFilter = Builders<MyElement>.Filter.Lte(e => e.Count, maxCount);

// Create a filter for matching documents with MyElements that have the required Count
var documentFilter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.All(doc => doc.MyElements, [what to fill in here?]);

// Query the collection and retrieve the matching documents
var results = collection.Find(documentFilter).ToList();
```

Is the correct way to do this using the Filter.All() option? Or is there another way to do this using Builders?

Comment: I doubt that there is any simple way in MongoDB .NET syntax or MongoDB query operator to filter based on your criteria. I think this query is what you want: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F1SmGUhrnqp)